# Dynamic field choices in django forms based

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a django form in which I have country_name and state_name fields. Based on the country_name entered the states are fetched from StateAndCountryList model and should be displayed as a dropdown in the form field state_name. Here is my code.

```
class myForm(forms.ModelForm):
    country_name = forms.CharField(required = True)
    state_name =  forms.ChoiceField(widget = forms.Select(), choices =[ (obj.id, obj.district) for obj in StateAndCountryList.objects.filter(country=country_name)], required = True,)
```

But this isn't working. Need help doing this in proper way.

Answer (score -1):

This could be done by initially loading all the state values in `state_name` field and when a country is selected you could fire an ajax call that would fetch all the states for that selected country from the `StateAndCountryList`.

Comment: Can you give an example pls?